# How to print the output of Tinkerpop (TinkerGraph) queries in a java environment?

Tags: java, tinkerpop3

I have been working with Apache Tinkerpop 3.3 in a Java environment and I have been having trouble printing the output of the queries I make. For example, when I use the following code:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = tg.traversal();
System.out.println(g.V(V1).in().values().fold());
```

The output I get is just the description of the action (something like this).

```
[GraphStep(vertex,[v[0]]), VertexStep(IN,vertex)]
```

I have tried adding .toList() but it still doesn't work. I have gone through the documentation of TinkerPop but it hasn't been of much help. What can I do to actually print the output of the query (in this case, the list of vertices connected to the Vertex V1) on the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
System.out.println(g.V(V1).in().values().fold());
```

you are printing the `Traversal` instance itself and not the result. The result needs to be iterated out in some way - result iteration is described in some detail in [The Gremlin Console Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration).

Now, you do say that you that you appended `.toList()` to the end of that traversal, so I'm not sure why you would still have a problem if your code looked like this:

```
System.out.println(g.V(V1).in().values().fold().toList());
```

Though this should probably be all you need since `fold()` is already returning a single `List`:

```
System.out.println(g.V(V1).in().values().fold().next());
```

I would validate that your traversal actually returns data, as either of the above should show your output.